# Event Registration Scope in C#

Tags: c#, events, garbage-collection

Could it be that the 'completed' event handler won't be called due to resource freeing by the GC?

```
public void StartVideo(WerCamera camera)
    {
        Credential creadential = new Credential() { Email = CurrentUser.Email, Password = CurrentUser.Password, SessionNumber = SessionNumber};
        CommandsClient client = new CommandsClient();
        client.StartVideoCompleted += client_StartVideoCompleted;
        client.StartVideoAsync(int.Parse(camera.Id), creadential, ClientInfo);

        client.CloseAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible since you are losing all references to client once the function returns.

`client.StartVideoCompleted += client_StartVideoCompleted;` ends up holding a reference to the object with the client_StartVideoCompleted function but that is not reciprocated. You'll need to keep a reference to the created client somehow.

Comment: Thanks,So what is the best practice for calling WCF services (CommandsClient) and registering to their events?  Thanks, janiv.

Comment: I don't really use wcf much but given the snippet of code you have posted I would probably have a List<CommandsClient> field in that class. Add each new command to the list before exiting that function and then remove the command from the list in client_StartVideoCompleted. You may need to lock access to the list if the event is being called in a different thread to the creatin - just something to be aware of.